# Should Objective-C constants be wrapped by the implementation block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an iOS application I'm writing. I've moved away from `#define` to create my constant values. I have a few questions regarding the use of these style declarations: `NSString *const segueToMainMenu`

1. If I'm using these internally, I'm placing them inside the .m file. However, should I be placing these wrapped around the `@implementation` block or outside of it or does it matter? I'm thinking inside, because they are specific to the implementation and not global, but I'm not sure. Any details are appreciated.
2. If I'm creating a more global scope using the `extern` keyword and I'm using a Constants file pair (Constants.h/Constants.m) do I need to place those in the `@interface` section and then define them in the `@implementation` section? What is the benefit of that vs the old way of just using a Constants.h file and including it with other headers? Why do I now need two files?
3. Is the standard practice still to name the constants with a "k" prefix (e.g. `kAnimationDuration`) or should I now be doing something like `MainMenuViewControllerAnimationDuration`? I'm imagining yes and if so, does it matter for the constants from number 1 (i.e. not extern) how I name them? In other words, are those visible outside of my implementation?

Clarification is much appreciated.

Comment: You can't put `NSString * Constant = @"Contant"` in a .h file, because it's possible for that line to be #included in multiple .c/.m files.. and you will end up with a multiply-defined symbol. That's why you _declare_ the constant in a .h, and _define_ it (once) in the corresponding .c/.m file.

Comment: Ah... Gotcha. I hadn't thought about it like that, but when you put it that way it makes complete sense and I feel slightly embarrassed for needing to ask ;)

Comment: Lew .. are you familiar with using singletons?  Sometimes constants are just a bad idea and there's a better way.  Usually (not every time but usually) when you have constants for some reason - it's just not the best way.  BTW the preprocessor is great: one could argue that in the very rare cases you need constants, they should 'work well as a macro'. try to use more categories, more classes, less constants!

Comment: @JoeBlow well--constants like this are singletons really. Although I suppose the compiler _might_ "unique" all your strings if you use macros

Comment: hey @nielsbot !  A good technical point but i believe it's not a language-mechanic issue, really to be honest. The overwhelming issue is absolute clarity, and to add monetary value to the code for the client (or yourself) by making it incredibly elegant.  What you want is hot, Claudia Schiffer -esque code, that is really beautiful. Compiler techniques come and go eh ...

Comment: @lewiguez I don't think it's that obvious :)

Comment: Another good answer here is "nothing should be a constant anymore, use parse.com" -- it's kind of true. Everything should be totally flexible, if not from the cloud.  Another way to look at it is, encapsulate every class down to the point where it has only one constant (say, "a URL to contact pubnub") or whatever, and then never think about it again and only have that string/etc in that one file as a macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't matter whether you place them inside the implementation block or not—only methods are part of the class implementation, so the scope of constants won't change regardless.

The `k` prefix is a bit dated now. The usual way is to name constants as `<prefix><name>`, such as "MDSomeConstant".

Comment: Be careful with the term "implementation block". When I read that I think of the curly braces that you would put private ivars in. That's a big difference from simply putting the global variables after `@implementation` (but outside the curly braces).